# How hard are treasure hunt adventures?

Tags: card-hunter

I'm around level 5 and I've been having fun, so I figured I'd support the makers by buying the $25 basic pack or whatever it's called. I have access to 2 treasure hunt adventures, one level 6 and one level 7. I've done the dungeon rescue adventure, which was relatively challenging, though I completed it (just barely) on the first try.

At level 6 how challenging will the level 6 treasure hunt be? Should I try to level up to 7 or 8, or go ahead and give it a shot once I hit 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I didn't feel a meaningful difference in difficulty between treasure hunts and normal quests. I did face some challenging quests, but they were not necessarily treasure hunts.

I'd suggest you go ahead and keep doing quests which are the same as your level.